# System.CommandLine won't invoke a method on a Moq object

Tags: c#, moq

System.CommandLine is a very useful and powerful NuGet package from MS for parsing command-line arguments. Here it isn't working properly when passed a mock object instead of a real, concrete object.

I am testing `ApplicationService` to check if it calls this method with the correct arguments:

```
IBuilderService.BuildForSingleTable(table, model, schema, overwrite)
```

`ApplicationService` is set up as follows:

```
private readonly Mock<IBuilderService> _builderMock = new();
_sut = new ApplicationService(_loggerMock.Object, _configMock.Object, _builderMock.Object);
```

And my test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task RunAsync_with_root_command_invokes_build_single_table()
{
    // Arrange
    var tableName = "testTableName";
    var modelName = "testModelName";
    var schemaName = "testSchemaName";
    var args = new[] { tableName, "--model", modelName, "--schemaName", schemaName, "--overwrite" };

    _builderMock.Setup(x => x.BuildForSingleTable(
        It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals(tableName)), 
        It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals(modelName)), 
        It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals(schemaName)), 
        It.Is<bool>(x => x))).Verifiable();

    // Act
    await _sut.RunAsync(args);

    // Assert
    _builderMock.Verify(m => m.BuildForSingleTable(
        It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals(tableName)),
        It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals(modelName)),
        It.Is<string>(s => s.Equals(schemaName)),
        It.Is<bool>(x => x)));
}
```

The app service ctor and `RunAsync` method:

```
public ApplicationService(ILogger<ApplicationService> logger, IConfiguration config, IBuilderService builderService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _config = config;
    _builderService = builderService;
}

public async Task<int> RunAsync(string[] cliArgs)
{
    var rootCommand = BuildCommandTree();

    rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create(delegate (string table, string? model, string? schema, bool overwrite, IConsole console)
    {
        _builderService.BuildForSingleTable(table, model, schema, overwrite);
    });
    return rootCommand.Invoke(cliArgs);
}
```

When I directly run the console app, `Invoke` returns 0 and `BuildForSingleTable` is invoked and runs just fine. When I run the test, `rootCommand.Invoke` returns 1 and `BuildForSingleTable` is not invoked.

Comment: I would guess that you need to setup mocked object before passing it to the constructor with `_mock.Object`

Comment: @Fabio Nope, I just tried that with the same exception from Moq

Comment: When you run test what you get in `rootCommand` ?

Comment: @ProfK Replace `It.Is` with to `It.IsAny` for both the Setup and Verify to make sure that it's getting called in the first place with anything. If that doesn't work, check the Test Explorer Output down the bottom to see if there are any Standard Errors. With the CLI tools, you might get `Unrecognized command or argument...` errors come up.

Comment: @Hayden I've been a bit slow on the uptake here: Even still using `It.Is` my `RunAsync` method does get invoked, but it doesn't call `BuildForSingleTable`. The `root command.InvokeAsync` returns 1, indicating a runtime error. I think this  is because `_builderService` is a mock. When it is a concrete object, `InvokeAsyns` returns 0.

Comment: @ProfK Include what is `rootCommand ` and how it is built. Also what is `CommandHandler.Create` suppose to do? It would appear that the `delegate` is not being invoked. Include the actual exception message.

Comment: @ProfK I also believe that command line is unaware that it is being invoked in a unit test and not actual run time, so may be trying to invoke an actual command. It is possible that 3rd part dependency may need to be abstracted to avoid the tight coupling that is affecting your expected behavior.